# C# gRPC Unhandled Exception on CallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall call

Tags: windows, c#

I have a .NET gRPC server / client application. It did already works. But now I get on all server calls the follow error in the grpc client:

```
*Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Cancelled, Detail="Cancelled")
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg) in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Internal\AsyncCall.cs:Zeile 78.
   bei Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request) in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\DefaultCallInvoker.cs:Zeile 46.
   bei Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.<BlockingUnaryCall>b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx) in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Interceptors\InterceptingCallInvoker.cs:Zeile 51.
   bei Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation) in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\ClientBase.cs:Zeile 174.
   bei Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request) in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Interceptors\InterceptingCallInvoker.cs:Zeile 48.*
```

I undid everything. The error remains. I just don't know the cause.

I am using .NET 4.7.2, Grpc 1.21.0 and Google.Protobuf 3.8.0.

Comment: You can enable extra logging with https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md perhaps that helps you find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When I have seen the error:

```
Status(StatusCode=Cancelled, Detail="Cancelled")
```

without having an actual cancellation happen, the call has always had a null return value.

If you have access to the gRPC server code, set a breakpoint to see where you are able to view the return value.